# Unlock LUKS encrypted Debian root with key file on boot partition

Tags: debian, luks, initramfs, cryptsetup

I'm trying to decrypt the Debian root with a key file stored in the boot partition (decrypted partition). This will break the security, but it doesn't matter now. I have to conclude this successfully or die trying.

I have created the hooks to the `initramfs` and the key file is on the `/boot` directory inside the `initrd.img-*` file. The path to the key file (`/boot/keyfile`) is on the `/etc/crypttab` file.

I updated the `initramfs` with `sudo update-initramfs -u` but I received this message: `cryptsetup: WARNING: target sdaX_crypt uses a key file, skipped.`

Ignoring the message and rebooting results in a unbootable disk. The message `Gave up waiting for root device.` is displayed and drops to `initramfs` shell.

In the `initramfs` environment the `cryptsetup` don't exists. *(It should exists?)*

Seens that the `update-initramfs -u` "thinks" the `sdaX_crypt` device will be mounted in another way and don't configure to decrypt with the keyfile.

*How can I do that?*

Comment: "In the initramfs environment the cryptsetup don't exists." Not sure what that means.

Comment: That means that the cryptsetup binary did not get included in the initramfs archive.

Answer (score 12):

Keyfiles matching the shell-style (globbing) pattern KEYFILE_PATTERN defined in `/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook` will be included in the initramfs, but the other keyfiles will not, according to Debian's cryptsetup docs:

- For Debian 9: `/usr/share/doc/cryptsetup/README.{initramfs,Debian}.gz`
- For Debian 10: `/usr/share/doc/cryptsetup{-initramfs/README.initramfs,-run/README.Debian}.gz`.

I am not sure about previous versions of Debian.

These files are readable with `zless filename.gz`, but here it is the relevant part, for convenience and future reference.

> ### 12. Storing keyfiles directly in the initrd
>
> Normally devices using a keyfile are ignored (with a loud warning), and the key file itself is
>   not included in the initrd, because the initramfs image typically
>   lives on an unencrypted /boot partition. However in some cases it is
>   desirable to include the key file in the initrd; for instance recent
>   versions of GRUB support booting from encrypted block devices,
>   allowing an encrypted /boot partition.
>
> Among the key files listed in the crypttab(5), those matching the
>   value of the environment variable KEYFILE_PATTERN (interpreted as a
>   shell pattern) will be included in the initramfs image. For instance
>   if /etc/crypttab lists two key files /etc/keys/{root,swap}.key, you
>   can add the following to /etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook to add
>   them to the initrd.
>
> KEYFILE_PATTERN="/etc/keys/*.key"
>
> Furthermore if the initramfs image is to include private key material,
>   you'll want to create it with a restrictive umask in order to keep
>   non-privileged users at bay.  This can be achieved by adding the
>   following to /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf.
>
> UMASK=0077

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `keyscript` option in your crypttab instead (man crypttab). Just create a script that echos your passphrase and set it as the keyscript argument, then regenerate your ramfs. You don't need any hooks, and you don't need to put the script in /boot/.

`vg1-root_crypt UUID=94a3b301-123-12-a3-ea0403 none luks,keyscript=/etc/echo-root-luks-pass`

I don't know why the initramfs hooks for cryptsetup prohibit you from just having the keyfile listed in crypttab. Probably don't want to condone such behavior.

P.S. I don't think that it breaks the security, it just weakens it more or less depending on how secure your /boot partition is. You could for example /boot off a USB drive, and keep the USB in you socks etc.

Comment: This should be the preferred answer. It's the easiest to implement, and it works flawlessly (at least on Debian, `update-initramfs` skips both the `keyfile` option for the root partition, and keyfiles not located on encrypted partitions).

Answer (score 3):

To really ignore the message and do not skip the partition, you need (at least) comment out/delete the `return 1` in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptroot` after the line where the error message 
is written (around line 274 - depening on the used cryptsetup version). Beware that this file is by default managed by the package manager,
and therefore is overwritten at any update of the cryptsetup package.

Please read also https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=776409
for more information about the issue.

I have not tested it, there could be other reasons than the mentioned why the case of a keyfile is 
not considered.

Answer (score 1):

If my memory serves me well, your problem is that your fstab is modified to point to the encrypted partition, since you have booted from an unencrypted partition your fstab (while you are executing `update-initrd`) should point to your unencrypted volume. AFTER you have created the initrd image you can modify your fstab to point to the encrypted partition.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I have one disk with an unencrepted /boot partition on sda1 and the encrypted volume on sda5 partition. Inside the encrepted volume (sda5) there are LVM volumes: root and swap. The two LVM logical volumes are set in /etc/fstab while the luks in /etc/crypttab. Luks key files resides on the /boot/keyFile.bin

Answer (score 0):

I second @ignis' answer, but I would add that for that to work you need the `initramfs` option in your `/etc/crypttab` file, like this:

```
# <target name> <source device>             <key file>          <options>
mapper-name     /etc/disk/by-id/scsi_xxxxx  /etc/keys/luks.key  luks,initramfs
```

Obs: I would have made a comment on the answer but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do this for Ubuntu 22.04. That is, I wanted to add a keyfile to unlock the encrypted root partition. This was on a machine I am decommissioning as my workstation, and bypassing the boot prompt seemed easier and less risky than decrypting.

I am using a the custom liquorix kernel, installed via a PPA.

I created a keyfile and saved it as /root/keyfile following a tutorial.
To copy this into the initrams, I created an executable script  in /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks, called keyfile.sh with contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

PREREQ=""

prereqs() {
    echo "$PREREQ"
}

case $1 in
prereqs)
    prereqs
    exit 0
;;
esac

. /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions
copy_exec /root/keyfile /root/keyfile
exit $?
```

That step is commonly documented.

However, the boot process was failing and I was getting stuck in the initramfs shell. Getting back to normal boot was pretty easy, just run:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 cryptroot
```

and then exit the initramfs shell via ctrl-D

To fix the problem, I created another hook file:
/etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/cp_crypttab.sh
with contents

```
#!/bin/sh
cp /etc/crypttab "${DESTDIR}/cryptroot/crypttab"
exit 0
```

and of course it needs to be executable.

After `update-initramfs -u`
my boot works without interaction.

for reference:

```
[/etc/initramfs-tools/hooks] [] $ more /etc/crypttab
nvme0n1p3_crypt UUID=273c0e11-3421-4820-bf30-d256481950b4 /root/keyfile luks,discard
```