# Preventing boot prompting twice for encryption passphrase on Debian based OS

Tags: debian, arch-linux, grub2, luks, initramfs

A friend of mine has Debian without systemd running on a disk with full disk encryption (including /boot on the same partition as / using LVM). She is prompted twice for the encryption password when booting: Once by grub, and once by the kernel. Our goal is that she is prompted exactly once.

I have found a [this guide](https://wiki.parabola.nu/Installing_Parabola_on_Libreboot_with_full_disk_encryption_(including_/boot)) that works for Arch-based GNU/Linux claiming to overcome the problem. But it doesn't work for Debian-based GNU/Linux because at least one of the packages is a little different. Chapter 11 of the guide explains how to make a keyfile that the kernel can use after the drive has been unlocked. That way, the user is prompted exactly once. How would these steps be translated to Debian-based distribution? The following is the guide.

***Guide***

Boot up and log in as root or your user. Then generate the key file:

```
# dd bs=512 count=4 if=/dev/urandom of=/etc/mykeyfile iflag=fullblock
```

Insert it into the LUKS volume:

```
# cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sdX /etc/mykeyfile
```

...and enter your LUKS passphrase when prompted. Edit `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` to include the key in the FILES array, e.g.

```
FILES="/etc/mykeyfile"
```

Create the initramfs image from scratch:

```
# mkinitcpio -p linux-libre
# mkinitcpio -p linux-libre-lts
# mkinitcpio -p linux-libre-hardened
```

Add the following to the kernel (linux) line in your grub.cfg -- which you now know to do, see above! --, e.g. after `root=/dev/matrix/rootvol` if you've followed this guide:

```
# cryptkey=rootfs:/etc/mykeyfile
```

Finally, deny read access to the key file, even by root:

```
# chmod 000 /etc/mykeyfile
```

Comment: `GNU/Linux, but it doesn't work for Debian-based GNU/Linux` is not very useful ... what actually happens?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. At least one package (mkinitcpio) doesnt exist for debian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Debian 11 at least, if you have the `cryptsetup-initramfs` package installed, its `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptroot` script will parse your `/etc/crypttab` and, if I read the script correctly, will automatically detect if your root filesystem is on an encrypted container that is supposed to be unlocked by a keyfile, and will automatically include the keyfile to initramfs.

So, after the `cryptsetup luksAddKey` step, the Debian 11 equivalent would be to make sure the `cryptroot-initramfs` package is installed, add the keyfile definition to the root filesystem's `/etc/crypttab` line just like you were setting up a LUKS container for some non-root filesystem.

Using the same names as in your example, the `crypttab` line would be:

```
sdX_crypt /dev/sdX /etc/mykeyfile luks
```

or rather, you really should to use the UUID of the LUKS volume instead for robustness:

```
sdX_crypt UUID=... /etc/mykeyfile luks
```

Then run `update-initramfs -u -k all`.

The `sdX_crypt` is the name of the mapping device that will be used to access the encrypted content once the encryption is unlocked. Debian installer will default to creating the mapping device name by taking the basename of the encrypted device and adding the `_crypt` suffix, but I believe it can be customized too.

Since your friend uses LVM, you will need to run `lsblk` and see the `NAME` column of the LVM devices used for the root and `/boot` filesystems: those names will be of the form `VGname-LVname`. You'll need the `VGname` part, then run `pvs` as root and find the name of the PV containing the named VG. That should be something like `/dev/mapper/sdX_crypt`.

The hook script will be executed by `update-initramfs`. It will pick up the information from `/etc/crypttab` and automatically add the keyfile and the necessary script snippet to use it into the initramfs.

You won't need to add the boot option - the autogenerated initramfs script will have all the parameters it needs embedded in it.

The [link you posted in the comments](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/crypttab.html) can certainly be used, but you really should use [the `crypttab(5)` man page of your distribution](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/cryptsetup/crypttab.5.en.html) for the most accurate information.

Setting the protection for `/etc/mykeyfile` to `chmod 600` or less is a good idea. I'm not certain whether setting `chmod 000` is any use, but you can try it; worst case, you'll just need to type the encryption password twice at next boot, and then readjust the permissions and run `update-initramfs -u -k all` again.

Comment: Thanks for having a look. (1) Should crypttab be edited according to this? freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/crypttab.html ?? (2) What're you referring to by «edit as for a non-root filesystem»? (3) That reference makes us think the kernel already have this feature built in? Does that mean I can ignore the rest of the steps of the guide above, or should I follow the last steps of that guide (edit grub.cfg and change permissions?

Comment: Sorry - I wrote the initial answer while on mobile. The `/etc/crypttab` is not read directly by the kernel, but by the cryptsetup hook script of the initramfs generator, the `cryptsetup` command and/or the  `/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-cryptsetup-generator` binary (which will generate `systemd-cryptsetup@somefs.service` units to activate any encrypted container that is listed in crypttab and not activated after initramfs).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is really turning out to be a nice thread. I have changed the title and introduction to make it more generally applicable. I notice that in the guide we've followed, the definition of the object "rootfs" does not appear. Which object does rootfs refer to, and where can I find out what it is called on my friend's machine?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is really turning out to be a nice thread. I have changed the title and introduction to make it more generally applicable. I notice that in the guide we've followed, the definition of the object "rootfs" does not appear. Using the debian documentation, it makes me think it is the logical drive that contains /. The guide on parabola suggested to call it 'rootvol'. I should put that in the place of rootfs, correct?

Comment: Since you are not creating a new encrypted container, but setting up an alternate method to unlock an existing one, you'll need to find out its name. See my edit above.

Comment: It works now! We are so excited. There were some complaints from update-initramfs before implementing this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/527368/105800 Thanks for showing us how to do it!